# Error all products are updated when modifying the input field

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have several input fields that allow me to add or update discounts to the products added to the shopping cart:

```
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[3][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="3" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[6][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="1" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
<div class="bsk-dto">
    <input type="text" name="dtoupdate[10][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" value="0" class="dto" autocomplete="off" data-validation="number" data-validation-allowing="float">
</div>
```

This data is generated according to the items added to the cart:

[image]

I have added `$this` attributes in my ajax code so that when some of them are modified, it only updates the input field that is being modified, but unfortunately it does not work for me, if I modify one of those input fields, all of them are modified.

```
$(function() {
    $(document).on('input', '.dto', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        var formData = [];
        $('input[name^="dtoupdate"]').each(function() {
            formData.push(this.value);
        });

        var formData = $(this).serializeArray();

        var url = "update_cart.ini.php";

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data: formData,
            cache: false,
        })
        .done(function(data) {
            let res = JSON.parse(data);
            if(res.status){
                $('.alert-success').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-success').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            } else {
                $('.alert-danger').fadeIn();
                $('.alert-danger').html(res.message).delay(2000).fadeOut(2000);
            }
        })
        .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
            /*alert("Ajax Request fail");
            console.log(jqXHR.responseText);
            console.log("Request failed: " + textStatus );*/
        })
    });
});
```

What changes should I make so that it only updates data from the input that is being modified?

This is the error if I modify an input (input) the others are also modified here is a gif of the error:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Did you check whether the request is sent with only these IDs?

Comment: You overwrite the formData (which is not a FormData object) with the complete form. You likely want `const arrayOfValues = $('input[name^="dtoupdate"]').map(function() { return this.value }).get();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this to send only one field

```
const field = {}; 
field[this.name] = this.value; 

$.ajax({
  url: url,
  methodd: "POST",
  data: field,
```

Comment: This will send me this information
`{name: 'dtoupdate[1301][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]', value: '1'}` because in the previous example you gave me in comment I didn't see it send this type of information What do I have in the input fields?

Comment: Not with the code you have shown

Comment: And the code I posted will send you `{ "dtoupdate[1301][Normal][Normal][Normal][1][%]" : "1" }`

Comment: *if I modify an input field, all the inputs are modified or updated* - not with the code that you've provided.   Please create a *new* question with a *complete* snippet that *demonstrates* this issue.